# Gradle annotationProcessor Could not find org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

My gradle project's build does not works with gradle 7.4.2 and java 17.

There is my dependencies declaration :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context'
    api 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core'
    annotationProcessor 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen'
}
```

And stack when I run build my project:

```
Could not find org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:.
```

It worked finely before (gradle-7.3.2 and java 8)